# Add class to parent when child get a new class?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I add class `.myclass` to `li` when its child (`a.nav-link`) get class `.active`?

```html
<ul class="nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Depends on **when** it gets the class active?

Comment: just add it when you add `active` class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to do this by checking when user click on link -

```
$(".nav-link").click(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('active'))
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('myclass');
});
```

and second way is by running loop on all links -

```
$("ul li a").each(function(index) {
      if($(this).hasClass('active'))
      $(this).parent('li').addClass('myclass');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by this code if you using JQuery.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

//For ref add above script cdn

**If you have to assign this on page load then use this code in onload / ready .**

```
$("a.nav-link.active").parent('li').addClass('myclass');
```

**If you want to change this on click of `a` tab and page not get postback and click event is handled by `a` then.**

```
$("this").parent('li').addClass('myclass');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop in anchor tag inside li and add your desire class in it's parent if it has class active.

```js
$("ul li a").each(function(index) {
  if($(this).hasClass('active'))
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('myclass');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```